# How to create table with different rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create the table in the picture. But I am not really successful with this and I couldn't understand the logic.

[image]

My html code:

```
<table>
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">1</td>
            <td>a2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you can help me with this, i would be really glad.

Comment: He asked twice. Let's help him!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `colspan` to merge columns. And then I use a table in the table to make split a cell into 3 rows.

```css
.table-inside {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.table-inside td {
  padding: 0;
}

.table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tarih</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="p-0">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-inside">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>T</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>T</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>T</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Saat</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS -

```
  table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  .border-top-hide {
    border-top: 0;
  }
  .border-bottom-hide {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
```

HTML -

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Tarih</td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="border-bottom-hide"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Saat</td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td class="border-top-hide"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```